# How can I return a color in a get method using a bool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main goal is to be able to use either the custom or default colors.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

// Implementation from UnityEditor.Graphs.GraphGUI
public static class GraphBackground
{
    public static Color CustomkGridMinorColorDark;
    public static Color CustomkGridMajorColorDark;
    public static Color CustomkGridMinorColorLight;
    public static Color CustomkGridMajorColorLight;

    public static bool defaultColors = true;

    private static readonly Color kGridMinorColorDark = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.18f);
    private static readonly Color kGridMajorColorDark = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.28f);
    private static readonly Color kGridMinorColorLight = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);
    private static readonly Color kGridMajorColorLight = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.15f);

    private static Color gridMinorColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin)
                return kGridMinorColorDark;
            else
                return kGridMinorColorLight;
        }
    }

    private static Color gridMajorColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin)
                return kGridMajorColorDark;
            else
                return kGridMajorColorLight;
        }
    }
```

I want to use the flag defaultColors to decide if to use the default colors or the custom colors.

The problem is that if I'm doing :

```
private static Color gridMinorColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultColors == true)
            {
                if (EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin)
                    return kGridMinorColorDark;
                else
                    return kGridMinorColorLight;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting error on the get since it's not returning anything now.

Comment: In `get {}` you need to write code for `customColors` i.e else part

Answer (score 0):

Well simply not all cases of `gridMinorColor` return a valid value.
In your case you can also use the [conditional operator `?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to make your code a bit more easy to read/write

```
private static Color gridMinorColor
{
    get
    {
        if (defaultColors)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin ? kGridMinorColorDark : kGridMinorColorLight;
        }

        // equals the else part
        // but since you return within the if you can skip the else keyword
        return EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin ? CustomkGridMinorColorDark : CustomkGridMinorColorLight;
    }
}
```